# How to properly apply rule of 5 (or zero?) to a class containing a vector of custom objects with strings

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rule-of-zero

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around ownership and maximizing performance with moves. Imagine this hypothetical set of classes emulating an Excel workbook.

```
namespace Excel {

class Cell
{
public:
  // ctors
  Cell() = default;
  Cell(std::string val) : m_val(val) {};
  // because I have a custom constructor, I assume I need to also
  // define copy constructors, move constructors, and a destructor.
  // If I don't my understanding is that the private string member 
  // will always be copied instead of moved when Cell is replicated 
  // (due to expansion of any vector in which it is stored)? Or will 
  // it be copied, anyways (so it doesn't matter or I could just 
  // define them as default)

  value() const { return m_val; }; // getter (no setter)
private:
  std::string m_val;
}

class Row
{
public:
  // ctors
  Row() = default;
  Row(int cellCountHint) : m_rowData(cellCountHint) {}

  // copy ctors (presumably defaults will copy private vector member)
  Row(const Row&) = default;
  Row& operator=(Row const&) = default;

  // move ctors (presumably defaults will move private vector member)
  Row(Row&& rhs) = default;
  Row& operator=(Row&& rhs) = default;

  // and if I want to append to internal vector, might I get performance
  // gains by moving in lieu of copying, since Cells contain strings of
  // arbitrary length/size?
  void append(Cell cell) { m_rowData.push_back(cell); };
  void append(Cell &&cell) { m_rowData.push_back(std::move(cell)); };
private:
  std::vector<Cell> m_rowData;
}

}
```

And so on:

- A Worksheet class would contain a vector of Rows
- A Workbook class would contain a vector of Worksheets

I felt no need to implement these last two for the MWE since they are effectively duplicative of Row (my *assumption* is they would be identical to the design of Row).

It's confusing to me to understand if it's ok to rely on the defaults or if I should be defining my own move constructors (and not keeping them default) to ensure the private vector member variable is *moved* rather than copied, but this is all very confusing to me and I can only seem to find overly simplistic examples of a class with nothing but members of built-in types.

Comment: *"because I have a custom constructor, I assume I need to also define copy constructors, move constructors, and a destructor.*" No you do not. `Cell` is fine as-is, copyable and movable. `Row` doesn't need explicitly declared copy and move constructors/assignment operators either.

Comment: If you are going to maximize performance then you should not accept strings by value.

Comment: @VTT is there a way to move the string in constructor? Or do you recommend something else?

Comment: @VTT or writing `Cell(std::string val) : m_val(std::move(val)) {};` which is what [clang-tidy: modernize-pass-by-value](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-pass-by-value.html) suggests.

Comment: Sure, you can write two constructors: once accepting an l-value reference to const-qualified string and initializing field by copying it and another once accepting an rvalue reference to non-const-qualified string and moving it. @t.niese The serious draw back of that approach is that a temporary object will always be constructed destroyed on the caller's side.

Comment: @VTT then what do you recommend, specifically?

Comment: @ArthurDent As I wrote above, I recommend adding two constructors that would efficiently handle both copy and move scenarios.

Comment: @VTT ok I misunderstood your critique of t.niese's example to mean you did not approve of that method, which is exactly how i would make the constructor to move string, only I would use `string &&val` as parameter, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a class deals with the ownership of a resource, then that class should ONLY manage that resource. It shouldn't do anything else. In this case define all 5 (rule of 5).

Else, a class doesn't need to implement any of the 5 (rule of 0).

Simple as that.

---

Now, I've seen these rules formulated as follows: if a class defines any of the 5 then it should define all of them. Well, yes, and no. The reason behind it is: if a class defines any of the 5 then that is a strong indicator that the class has to manage a resource, in which case it should define all 5. So, for instance if you define a destructor to free a resource then the class is in the first category and should implement all 5, but if you define a destructor just to add some debug statements or do some logging, or because the class is polymorphic then the class is not the first category, so you don't need to define all 5.

If your class is in the second category and you define at least one of the 5, then you should explicitly `=default` the rest of the 5. That is because the rules on when cpy/move ctors/assignments are implicitly declared are a bit complicated. E.g. defining a dtor prevents the implicit declaration of move ctor & assigment

---

> ```
> // because I have a custom constructor, I assume I need to also
> // define copy constructors, move constructors, and a destructor.
> ```

Wrong. A custom constructor is not part of the 5.

---

All of your classes should follow the rule of 0, as neither of them manages resources.

Actually it's pretty rare for a user code to need to implement a rule of 5 class. Usually that's implemented in a library. So, as a user, almost always for to the rule of 0.

---

The default copy/move ctors/assignments do the expected thing: the copy ones will copy each member, and the move ones will move each member. Well, in the presence of members that aren't movable, or have only some of the 5, or have some of the 5 deleted, then the rules go a little more complex, but there are no unexpected behaviors. The default are good.

Comment: *"if you define a destructor ... because the class is polymorphic then the class is not the first category, so you don't need to define all 5"* You still might need to `=default` the remaining 4. Defining a destructor prevents move ctor&assignment from being generated (no good for performance), and it you `=default` those, you also need to `=default` copy ctor&assignment if you want your class to be copyable.